# "Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error." When trying to install WooCommerce plugin on WordPress, How can i fix it?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Warning: include_once(/home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 24

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 24

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WooCommerce' not found in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php(38): WC() #1 /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2141): include('/home/vol9_6/ep...') #2 /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-admin/plugins.php(175): plugin_sandbox_scrape('woocommerce/woo...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_24241039/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 34

---

That is the error that I'm getting,I would really appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: Try reinstalling the plugin. Seems as if some files where not properly installed or got corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If reinstalling the plugin does not work then disable all plugins and then try and activate that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solve this one, First i did go to my cpanel to access my data and delete my woocommerce plugin there, then i go to this site https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/ to download the latest version, unzip it then use "FileZilla" Client software which is free to manually put the unzip woocommerce plugin to my Web Database.